# Win32 WndProc as class member

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

Is there a way to wrap WndProc as private member?

If I have this:

```
class Window
{
public:
    Window();
    virtual ~Window();
    void create();

private:
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

And in my `create()` this:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) &Window::WndProc;
```

I get this warning:

`warning: converting from 'LRESULT (Window::*)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) {aka long int (Window::*)(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned int, long int)}' to 'WNDPROC {aka long int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned int, long int)}' [-Wpmf-conversions]`

And my window `HWND` is `NULL`, `GetLastError()` also returns 0.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it static:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Comment: well, thats interesting.. it worked for me. but i am calling a number of functions from wndProc, and none of them are static, so how can this be achieved?

I do not want to make them static..

Answer (score 7):

You should add the `static` modifier to it.

The reason for this, is that when it's a member function (which I believe is a `__thiscall` in Visual C++), it's actually just a C function taking `this` as the first parameter. This would look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(Window& this, HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

If you make it static, the compiler gets rid of the first `Window& this` parameter, making it compatible with `lpfnWndProc` .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to include a WndProc as a class member. Furthermore, you can modify other class members from it. The trick is to use two WndProc functions, one of them static.

Comment: To add to this, the second part of the trick is to set a pointer to the C++ class instance on the window's win32 class, by setting `cbWndExtra` to the size of a pointer, and using `SetWindowLongPtr` to set the pointer. Then in your static method, use `GetWindowLongPtr` to fetch the pointer to the C++ class, and use it to call your instance-specific method.