# How do I call wndproc on WNDCLASSEX from a class in C++

Tags: c++, directx-9, imgui

I'm trying to make an ImGui DX9 Window. However I get an error when I try to reference the wndproc function on the WNDCLASSEX structure.

When I try to pre-define the `wndproc` function as static I get an error: `cannot overload static and non-static member functions with the same parameter types`.

I already tried to call the function directly like so: `menu::wnd_proc`.

When I try to call the function without `static` I get this error on the function: `a value of type "LRESULT (__stdcall menu::*)(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "WNDPROC"`.

Here's my function

```cpp
#include "ui.hpp"

bool menu::render( )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {
        sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ),
        CS_CLASSDC,
        menu::wnd_proc,
        0L,
        0L,
        GetModuleHandle( NULL ),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        _T( "ImGui Example" ),
        NULL
    };

    ...
}
```

Here's the `ui.hpp` header file

```cpp
#pragma once

class menu
{
public:

    bool render( );

private:
    LPDIRECT3D9 g_pD3D = NULL;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS g_d3dpp = {};

    static LRESULT WINAPI wnd_proc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

private:
    ...

    LRESULT WINAPI wnd_proc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {
        if ( ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam ) )
            return true;

        switch ( msg )
        {
            case WM_SIZE:
                if ( g_pd3dDevice != NULL && wParam != SIZE_MINIMIZED )
                {
                    g_d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = LOWORD( lParam );
                    g_d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = HIWORD( lParam );
                    menu::reset_device( );
                }
                return 0;
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                if ( ( wParam & 0xfff0 ) == SC_KEYMENU )
                    return 0;
                break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                ::PostQuitMessage( 0 );
                return 0;
        }
        return ::DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
    }
};


extern IMGUI_IMPL_API LRESULT ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
```

Comment: `wndproc` is a `C` language call-back and needs to be a non-member or static class member function.  A member function would need the implied `this` parameter and `C` call-backs can't do this (as they know nothing about `C++` calling conventions).

Comment: As I said, I tried to define it as static. But I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Post the error would help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Win32 WndProc as class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424150/win32-wndproc-as-class-member)

Comment: The error is already on the post. "When I try to pre-define the wndproc function as static I get an error: `cannot overload static and non-static member functions with the same parameter types.`"

Comment: You have the declaration of `wnd_proc` as `static` and the definition as __non__-`static`. Make them both `static`.

Comment: @dialer I'm already defining wndproc as a static function.

Comment: I made them both static, and now getting errors on `g_pd3dDevice`, `g_d3dpp` and `menu::reset_device()`. `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`

Comment: Sorry, I stopped reading here: `this->wnd_proc`. This is wrong if it's static.

Comment: That is expected now read the post @dialer linked.

Comment: @dialer, It's defined as: `menu::wnd_proc` and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't found the solution there.

Comment: You can't use data members in a static function. It can't be non-static because how would a function pointer hold the class object when it's a simple pointer to a function? You need to pass your user data through the channel `CreateWindow` provides, and there are [plenty of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270673/c-c-windows-how-to-keep-track-of-hwnd-context-data) on how to do that. C callbacks require the callback itself to have a system of passing user data rather than making everyone pay that cost when they use a function pointer.

Comment: Can someone enlight me with some examples? I still didn't get it

Comment: Last answer in the linked post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28131208/3370124

Comment: @RichardCritten That's exactly what I'm doing. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't call the non-static function with the same name as the static function.